# Why doesn't dataset's foreach method require an encoder, but map does?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset, apache-spark-encoders

I have two datasets: `Dataset[User]` and `Dataset[Book]` where both `User` and `Book` are case classes. I join them like this:

`val joinDS = ds1.join(ds2, "userid")`

If I try to `map` over each element in `joinDS`, the compiler complains that an encoder is missing:

`not enough arguments for method map: (implicit evidence$46: org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[Unit])org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[Unit].
Unspecified value parameter evidence$46.
Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset.`

But the same error does not occur if I use `foreach` instead of `map`. Why doesn't `foreach` require an encoder as well? I have imported all implicits from the spark session already, so why does `map` require an encoder at all, when the dataset is a result of joining two datasets containing case classes)? Also, what type of dataset do I get from that join? Is it a `Dataset[Row]`, or something else?

Comment: Pretty sure you can't encode `Unit`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR** `Encoder` is required to transform the outcome to the internal Spark SQL format and there is no need for that in case of `foreach` (or any other sink).

Just take a look at the signatures. [`map`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@map[U](func:T=%3EU)(implicitevidence$6:org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[U]):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[U]) is

```
def map[U](func: (T) ⇒ U)(implicit arg0: Encoder[U]): Dataset[U]
```

so in plain words it transforms records from `T` to `U` and then uses the `Encoder` of `U` to transform the result to internal representation.

[`foreach`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@foreach(f:T=%3EUnit):Unit) from the other hand, is

```
def foreach(f: (T) ⇒ Unit): Unit
```

In other words it doesn't expect any result. Since there is no result to be stored, `Encoder` is just obsolete.

Comment: @vaer-k Then it would need `Encoder[T]`, not `Encoder[U]` (or both).